# Join two tables, count the first table based on multiple conditions in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to join two tables, count the first table based on multiple conditions in the second table

This is my tables :

1. category table

```
| id |category|
+----+--------+
| 1  | food   |
| 2  | drinks |
+----+--------+
```

2. product tabel

```
| id |category| name  | entry      | verified   |
+----+--------+--------------------+------------+
| 1  |   1    | rice  | 2020-05-13 | 2020-05-25 |
| 2  |   1    | noodle| 2020-05-18 | 0000-00-00 |
| 3  |   2    | Milk  | 2020-05-15 | 0000-00-00 |
| 4  |   2    | Syrup | 2020-05-20 | 0000-00-00 |
+----+--------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I want to get list of categories along with count of number of products verified as follow.

```
+----+--------+-------+----------+
| No |category| entry | verified |
+----+--------+-------+----------+
|  1 | food   |   1   |     1    |
|  2 | drinks |   2   |     0    |
+----+--------+-------+----------+
```

i process it with php script and mysql database. I have trouble to make query to get list of those categories
can anyone help me make the query? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to achieve the results you want:

```
SELECT c.id AS No,
       c.category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p.entry != '0000-00-00' AND p.verified = '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END) AS entry,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN p.verified != '0000-00-00' THEN 1 END) AS verified
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.category = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.category
```

Output:

```
No  category    entry   verified
1   food        1       1
2   drinks      2       0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGmKgVSrScLroEbatxFHR3/0)

In MySQL you can simplify the `COUNT` to a `SUM` of the condition, since MySQL treats booleans as 1 or 0 in a numeric context:

```
SELECT c.id AS No,
       c.category,
       SUM(p.entry != '0000-00-00' AND p.verified = '0000-00-00') AS entry,
       SUM(p.verified != '0000-00-00') AS verified
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN product p ON p.category = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.category
```

The output is the same for this query. [Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bGmKgVSrScLroEbatxFHR3/1)

Comment: I tried the script, and the result is `+----+--------+-------+----------+
| No |category| entry | verified |
+----+--------+-------+----------+
|  1 | food   |   3   |     1    |
|  2 | drinks |   0   |     0    |
+----+--------+-------+----------+
`

Comment: @priyo your data must be different to what you have shown in the question. My demo uses the data you supplied in the question and it gives the expected result

Comment: @priyo provide correct data. Nick's solution looks right.

Comment: My mistake; I read it completely the other way around. Strange. Maybe I need some coffee!

Comment: I just had one. Hence my super-quick reply! :-P

Comment: Could we do SUM(verified=...)?

Comment: @Strawberry in MySQL, absolutely. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes - I had already included a query in that form in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    cat.id as `No`,
    cat.category,
    SUM(IF(pro.verified = '0000-00-00' and pro.entry != '0000-00-00', 1, 0)) as entry,
    SUM(IF(pro.verified != '0000-00-00', 1, 0)) as verified
FROM
    category AS cat
    INNER JOIN
    product AS pro
    ON 
        cat.id = pro.category
GROUP BY
    pro.category;
```

Comment: thank @sachin kumara liyanage, but the resulr of your script like this: ` |  1 | food   |   3   |     1    |`

Comment: thank you @nich, I was wrong to copy your script, you are right. thank you for your help